# Execute loop after the first iteration

Tags: excel, vba

This script is kicking my butt.  One step forward 3 steps back. :)

I have a designated folder where my files sit and the script goes through them one at a time.  It looks for file names starting with N or V and then determines what range of cells it's going to copy/paste depending on the file type.

I am basing the script behavior off of the first column AFTER the first iteration.  After the script determines where it's going to paste the data in column A, column B data should be following suit based on the "firstRange" variable location and paste it right next to it using .Offset(-1,1).

I need the script to first line things up with the top, hence this code:

```
.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

After the first iteration, I need it to start basing things off of column A the following columns end up in the same row, which is where I use:

```
If fileName Like "V*.xls" > 1 Then
```

BUT - I don't know if that syntax is correct.  I'm trying to have it start running after the first iteration.

Here's a clip of code for columns A and B:

```
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
    Do While fileName <> ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)


If fileName Like "V*.xls" Then
    wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy
With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    Set firstRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        firstRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
ElseIf fileName Like "N*.xls" Then
    wbkCS.Worksheets("PON Cut Sheet").Range("AV3:AV2000").Copy
        With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    Set ponRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ponRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End If

If fileName Like "V*.xls" > 1 Then
    wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("AA4:AA2000").Copy
        With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
            firstRange.Offset(-1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
ElseIf fileName Like "V*.xls" Then
     wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("AA4:AA2000").Copy
    With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
       .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
ElseIf fileName Like "N*.xls" > 1 Then
    wbkCS.Worksheets("PON Cut Sheet").Range("AA3:AA2000").Copy
    With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
      firstRange.Offset(-1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
ElseIf fileName Like "N*.xls" Then
    wbkCS.Worksheets("PON Cut Sheet").Range("AA3:AA2000").Copy
    With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
      .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not the right syntax.

Infact `fileName Like "N*.xls"` will always be true or false. So it will never be `> 1` I.E. `fileName Like "N*.xls" > 1` will always evaluate to false.

What you probably want to do is have a boolean you use as a flag for executing your code. For Example:

```
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
dim hasRun as boolean
Do While fileName <> ""
...
    If fileName Like "V*.xls" AND hasRun Then 'This will never run the first time
...
hasRun = true
loop
```

The `...` represents lots of code I didn't display, as I wanted to make the important parts more clear.

Comment: Dan thank you!  I think this is what I need and I'm working on it now.  Will post in a bit.

Comment: Oh, and as for the syntax ... that's what I was going for.  I didn't know how to write it out, so was trying various things. :)  Thanks again!